# Lookup a column value in recordset based on the value of another column

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, lookup, recordset

I have a MySQL `SELECT` query (using `wpdb_custom->get_results()`) that returns two `UNSIGNED` `TINYINT` columns `Col_1` and `Col_2` for an arbitrary number of rows. What is the least costly way in PHP to lookup the value of `Col_2` from the **recordset** given a value of `Col_1`?

```
Emp_ID  Col_1    Col_2
120         3       11
120         5       17
120         6        8
120         8       13
120        11       10
```

So for example, the pseudo-code lookup function `lookup(6, $recordset)` would yield `8`.

Comment: could you print a portion of your recordset ? So we can more easily see how your returned array/object looks like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume your recordset to array will look something like this :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Emp_ID] => 120
            [Col_1] => 3
            [Col_2] => 11
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Emp_ID] => 120
            [Col_1] => 5
            [Col_2] => 17
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Emp_ID] => 120
            [Col_1] => 6
            [Col_2] => 8
        )
    ....
)
```

Now create ONCE per page a search array.

```
$search_array =array();
foreach( $recordSet as $key=>$data ){

        $search_array[$data['Col_1']]=$data['Col_2'];   
}
```

Then each time you need to find the value of Col_2 from Col_1 just use :

```
echo $search_array[6]; // will return 8
```

For the other way around with the same search array use array_search()

```
echo  array_search("8",$search_array); // will return 6
```

Comment: aaiyt, will fine-tune this to glove-fit my application. thanks, man! much app'd.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what are you planing to do and more important how often.

You can do it with MySQL-JOIN on the same table. Or you create a hash and compare the datasets. Or you use array_search().

Comment: thanks, @Kescha , but another query is not an option, since, as the question states, i need to perform the lookup on the already-returned recordset. hm.. how do you suggest i go about array_search() on a recordset? as to how often, this routine will have to be executed 7x24=168 times per page call. any thoughts?

Comment: If you have to execute this routine 168 per page call on the same dataset, than I would suggest to use the answer from Paolo_NL_FR. You pay a high cost for creating a hash, but than you have really low-cost access.